# model undefined on page reload

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I'm trying example from [this](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/) site. It works fine. But if i separate views,models,routers into separate file it gives me a problem. There is 3 views. WineList view, WineListItemView and winedetails view. WineList view takes collection of wine models as model and winelistItem and winedetails view takes wine as a model.
Router's code is like this

```
var app = app || {};
app.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
        "":"list",
        "wines/:id":"wineDetails"
    },

    initialize:function () {
        $('#header').html(new app.HeaderView().render().el);
    },
    list:function () {
        this.wineList = new app.WineCollection();
        this.wineListView = new app.WineListView({model:this.wineList});
        this.wineList.fetch();
        $('#sidebar').html(this.wineListView.render().el);
    },

    wineDetails:function (id) {
        if(this.wineList == undefined)
            {
                this.wineList = new app.WineCollection();
        this.wineListView = new app.WineListView({model:this.wineList});
        this.wineList.fetch();
        $('#sidebar').html(this.wineListView.render().el);
            }
        this.wine = this.wineList.get(id);
        if (app.router.wineView) app.router.wineView.close();
        this.wineView = new app.WineView({model:this.wine});
        $('#content').html(this.wineView.render().el);
    }
});
```

On page load it fetches models from server and displays list of wines in sidebar div of page. When i click on particular wine item its details will be displayed in content div of page. That all works fine. But when i reload that page which now contains details of particular,wine model of Winedetails view gives undefined .
I'm intializing the router on main page like this

**app.js**

```
var app = app || {};

$(function() {


})
app.router = new app.AppRouter(); 
Backbone.history.start();
```

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Backbone Cellar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="header"><span class="title">Backbone Cellar</span></div>

<div id="sidebar"></div>

<div id="content">
<h2>Welcome to Backbone Cellar</h2>
<p>
This is a sample application part of of three-part tutorial showing how to build a CRUD application with Backbone.js.
</p>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="/page2">Next page</a>
</div>
<!-- Templates -->
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-header">
    <span class="title">Backbone Cellar</span>
    <button class="new">New Wine</button>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-wine-list-item">
    <a href='#wines/<%= id %>'><%= name %></a>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="tpl-wine-details">
    <div class="form-left-col">
        <label>Id:</label>
        <input type="text" id="wineId" name="id" value="<%= id %>" disabled />
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<%= name %>" required/>
        <label>Grapes:</label>
        <input type="text" id="grapes" name="grapes" value="<%= grapes %>"/>
        <label>Country:</label>
        <input type="text" id="country" name="country" value="<%= country %>"/>
        <label>Region:</label>
        <input type="text" id="region" name="region"  value="<%= region %>"/>
        <label>Year:</label>
        <input type="text" id="year" name="year"  value="<%= year %>"/>
        <button class="save">Save</button>
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-right-col">
        <img height="300" src="../pics/<%= picture %>"/>
        <label>Notes:</label>
        <textarea id="description" name="description"><%= description %></textarea>
    </div>
</script>

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="js/models/WineModel.js"></script>
<script src="js/collections/WineListCollection.js"></script>
<script src="js/Views/WineListView.js"></script>
<script src="js/Views/WineListItemView.js"></script>
<script src="js/Views/WineDetailsView.js"></script>
<script src="js/Views/HeaderView.js"></script>
<script src="js/routers/routers.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>   

</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to this backbone technology. please tell me what am i missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.wineList.fetch();
```

fires an asynchronous request to your server, which means that the content will arrive (or not) at some point after executing this line, but your application execution continues whether the response arrived or not. On page reload (assume you have `wines/:id` in the URL) first you have to fetch the complete list of wines before accessing any particular wine from the collection.

You have to wait until is download the collection, and access the wine with id, after this request is finished.

So after initiating the request continue your application logic in the `success` callback:

```
this.wineList.fetch({
    success: function(model) {
        ...
        this.wine = model.get(id);
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't *need* to fetch the whole list, just loading the specific model should suffice: `this.wine = new WineModel({id: id}); this.wine.fetch();` -- while the fetch would still be asynchronous the model instance can be passed to the view immediately.

Comment: But winelist would also become empty when i reload the page